# You'll find me clean when something is full

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> You'll find me clean when something is full,
>   But mix me up and I'll brighten a room looking dull.
>
> Down a size, I'm one you'd never hire,
>   But shuffled again and I'm shared 'round a fire.
>
> Reduced once more, and later your insides may ache,
>   But reworked again and it's your thirst that I'll slake.

---

> Hopefully you didn't have too much trouble solving it. Any and all feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll find me clean when something is full,

> You plate is clean when you are full.

But mix me up and I'll brighten a room looking dull.

> An anagram of plate is petal, and flower petals make nice decorations.

Down a size, I'm one you'd never hire,

> plate-p=late, A late person

But shuffled again and I'm shared 'round a fire.

> An anagram of late is tale, and you share stories around the fire.

Reduced once more, and later your insides may ache,

> Late-l=ate/eat, and if you eat to much you can get a stomach ache.

But reworked again and it's your thirst that I'll slake.

> An anagram of Eat is Tea, you can drink tea if you are thirsty (Alternate is Ale from OP)

PS, love the puzzle :)

Comment: You nailed it! Well done! There is another answer I would accept for the last line as well, but yours was the more correct of the two

Comment: Is it perhaps "Ale"? @StalemateOfTuning

Comment: Yep, that's it!